# Map private DNS records to EC2 instances with CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm using `aws-cdk` to run 7 `ec2` instances which will be `MongoDB` nodes. I'm able to create them with their security group and stuff, but I don't understand how can I map those in private DNS.

```
for (inst i = 1; inst<8; inst++) {
  new ec2.Instance(this, 'mongodb' + i, {
  instanceType: new ec2.InstanceType('t3.medium'), 
  vpc: defaultVpc,
  securityGroup: mongoGroup },
  )}
```

After deployment names will be `${mongodb1/InstanceRole.Arn}, ${mongodb2/InstanceRole.Arn},...`

How can I set my private `DNS` records for those instances in `cdk`? I want to create a configuration in which all nodes will be listed like

```
 database1.test.com
 database2.test.com
 database3.test.com
 ...
```

Instead of

```
ec2-203-3-156-25.compute-1.amazonaws.com
ec2-201-1-191-21.compute-1.amazonaws.com
ec2-208-0-112-03.compute-1.amazonaws.com
...
```

because if I redeploy or restart, IP will change, and I will need again to change complete configuration, also these names are just not easy to remember. I guess I need to create private hosted zone, and then assign each IP address to `CNAME`, but wonder if can be done in cdk automatically?

Comment: One way is setting `privateIpAddress`. Another is using a network load balancer and adding all the instance to the target group.

Comment: tnx, any suggestions maybe how can i achieve load balancer with target group in cdk? appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [network load balancer (NLB)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-elasticloadbalancingv2.NetworkLoadBalancer.html) for that.

Something similar to:

```
import * as elbv2 from '@aws-cdk/aws-elasticloadbalancingv2';
import * as elasticloadbalancingv2_targets from '@aws-cdk/aws-elasticloadbalancingv2-targets';

// vpc = ...

const lb = new elbv2.NetworkLoadBalancer(this, 'lb', { vpc, internetFacing: false });
const listener = lb.addListener('listener', { port: 27017 });
listener.addTargets('target', {
  targets: [
    new elasticloadbalancingv2_targets.InstanceIdTarget(instance1.instanceId),
    new elasticloadbalancingv2_targets.InstanceIdTarget(instance2.instanceId),
    // ... more ...
  ]
});

// get domain name from lb.loadBalancerDnsName
```